# Optimizing GraphQL queries by including fields only if they hold a value?

Tags: node.js, graphql, query-optimization, theory, bandwidth

I have no idea if this is a good idea at all, really bad practice, so that's what I'd like to know.

Say I have a graphql server, which sends back stuff like this:

```graphql
[

    {
      name: "John"
      age: 55
      isSingle: false
      hasChildren: false
      lovesMusic: false #imagine more fields like these
    {,
     # ...loads of records of the same format here

]
```

Say the file is large and there are lots of records: Wouldn't it be a good idea to just strip it off the values that are false and *only* send something back whenever `isSingle / hasChildren / lovesMusic` is true, in order to save on bandwidth? Or is this a bad idea, making everything prone to error?

So in this example, I'd just send back:

```graphql
[

    {
      name: "John"
      age: 55 
    {,
    ...

]
```

I am worried because I have large graphql objects coming back from my queries, and lots of it is just fields that aren't filled out and that I thus won't need in my frontend.

Comment: what scale? ... server must return value for all queried properties, it can't choose what to return [maybe doable with middleware] ... use compression? ... use custom link or custom json type to encode/decode freely shaped responses?

Comment: Ok, if this is not even possible, then please apologise me asking. I was just wondering, as I am sending back a lot of 'empty' stuff, as it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding The whole point of **GraphQL** is to receive exactly the specified set of types and fields - *not more, not less.*

Altering the results with some middle ware or deleting fields containing `0`, `null`, `false` or `undefined` would be the violation of **Graphql** Specification. There's no point in using some kind of convention if you are going to violate it anyways.

Neverthless there are some options to consider for performance and bandwidth optimization:

#### using shorter names

you could use shorter field names in GraphQL schema. you could even come up with some kind of compression algorithm of your own. For example you could replace logical names with characters and then map them back to regular names on the front-end.

```
{
     name: "John"
     age: 55
     isSingle: false
     hasChildren: false
     lovesMusic: false
{
```

would become something like this:

```
{
     n: "John"
     a: 55
     s: f
     hC: f
     lM: f
}
```

then you could map the field names and values back on a front-end sacrificing some performance of course. You just need to have some dictionary object in javascript which stores shorter field names as key-s and longer ones as values:

```js
const adict = {
  "hC": "hasChildren",
  "lM": "lovesMusic",
  "n": "name",
  ...
}
```

Althrough this approach will shrink your data and save you some bandwidth, it is not the best practice application-wise. somehow I think it will make your code less flexible and less readable.

#### external libraries

there quite a few external libraries that could help you with reducing dataload. most popular ones being  [**Message Pack**](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) and [**Protocol buffers**](https://msgpack.org/index.html). These are very efficient and cleverly built technologies, but researching and integrating them in your solution might take some time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into these. I suspected that this wouldn't be good practice and ultimately not a great idea. It just seemed like such an obvious little thing I could do, to not have so much superfluous data around, but well. Thank you!